# Footer background color not the same as body

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

Im new to designing email html templates. My templates background color is a tan. When I preview it in a browser the footer, header, and bodies background color is #ffffff, which I want. When I put the code into mailchimp the footer becomes almost transparent and I only see the tan background, not the white. What is going on here? And how do I fix it?

```
<td>
    <!-- Start Social Box -->
    <hr>
    <table class="mobileTable" id="socialBox" style="background-color: white;margin-top: 20px;margin: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center">Spread the Word!</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a title="Share this event by email!" href="*|FORWARD|*" target="_blank"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/2438f5b8906cc79e7c55f3c68/images/email_template.png" alt="Share this event by email!"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a title="Share this event on Twitter!" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=*|URL:ARCHIVE|*%20via%20%40ascensionpress" target="_blank"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/2438f5b8906cc79e7c55f3c68/images/twitter.png" alt="Share this event on Twitter!"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a title="Pin it on Pinterest!" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=*|URL:ARCHIVE|*%20via%20%40ascensionpress" target="_blank"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/2438f5b8906cc79e7c55f3c68/images/pinterest.png" alt="Pin it on Pinterest!"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=*|URL:ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank" title="Share this event on Facebook!"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/2438f5b8906cc79e7c55f3c68/images/facebook.png" alt="Share this event on Facebook!"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End Social Box -->
</td>
```

Comment: Can't do anything without seeing the HTML

Comment: post the HTML code you have problem with

Comment: Don't use `style="background-color: white;`, but use `bgColor="#fff"` on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-color: transparent;` this will make that background transparent and then whenever you will change your bgcolor the table's bgcolor will also get changed!